# How to fetch the records from a table where joining date of an employee is less than 15th of every month?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the schema of my table EMP :

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (
 EMPNO               NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 ENAME               VARCHAR2(10),
 JOB                 VARCHAR2(9),
 MGR                 NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT EMP_SELF_KEY REFERENCES EMP (EMPNO),
 HIREDATE            DATE,
 SAL                 NUMBER(7,2),
 COMM                NUMBER(7,2),
 DEPTNO              NUMBER(2) NOT NULL);
```

I have to list the employees those who joined in company before 15th of the month , so here month can be any month and we have to list name of all employees. I am unable to extract the month from hiredate and year from hiredate along with **where** clause  as moth can be any month and year ranges from 1980 to 1990 so I will also have to check whether the year lies in the range of 1980-1990.

Comment: show  a data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: Say I have 4 employees Smith ,Adam, Ram and Michael. Smith has hiredate 15th Aug,1980 , Adam has hiredate 20th July ,1990 , Ram has hiredate 26th May,1983 and Michael has hiredate 3rd June ,1986. Now The output of my query should return all the employees whose hiredate is less than 15th of every month so only output should be Michael since his hiredate is 3rd June.

Comment: Your query is marked  as duplicated .. try if the answer proposed is useful  otherwise  post a new question with  proper sample of data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EXTRACT` on the `HIREDATE` and check if it is less than 15:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EXTRACT(day FROM HIREDATE) < 15
```

More about `EXTRACT` function: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM EMP 
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATECOL) < 15 
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATECOL) BETWEEN 1980 AND 1990;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select * from EMP where  to_char(hiredate,'DD') < 15 and to_char(hiredate,'YYYY') between 1980 and 1990
```

Comment: Mixing character and numeric data types is not going to work well for comparisons of this type.

Comment: It does work well , give it a try

Comment: Only because the comparison  number, 15, has two digits. If it had one then it would not, so it's not a very general solution. Extract() is better